# Write unsaved Vim buffer to file without making it saved

Tags: vim

I open a new, unsaved buffer in Vim with `:enew`. My status line says "[No Name]".

If I do `:w /tmp/foo`, the status line changes to "/tmp/foo".

How can I write the contents to a file while keeping the buffer unsaved (unmodified, unnamed)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to have the buffer unsaved, but save the contents to another file, you can try this trick:

```
:%!tee new-filename
```

This will work only on a UNIX system as it executes external `tee` command.

On the other hand, if you want to name the buffer, but leave it unsaved, try this:

```
:file new-filename
```

To learn more, read

```
:help :file_f
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion, but this is the inverse of what I'm looking for :) What I want: save on disk, but don't give the buffer a name. What you're suggesting: don't save on disk, but give the buffer a name.

Comment: And once the buffer has a name you can write the contents of that buffer to a different file (`:enew<cr>:file /tmp/bar<cr>:w /tmp/foo`) without the buffer becoming associated with that file, because only the unnamed buffer will do that, correct?

Comment: @buff Oh yeah, the edit does the trick. Thank you! I'll mark this as accepted, but maybe you could edit the answer to put the tee bit at the top?

Comment: @buff Thank you! @jjaderberg Yup, you're right. Since `:w` will not rename the buffer of a saved file, I incorrectly assumed it would do the same with an unsaved file.

Comment: @HenrikN That's my understanding, except I don't think there has to be a saved file. It's enough to give the buffer a name to prevent it from assuming the name that you give for an argument to `:write`. If you did `:enew scratch` you should be fine writing the contents to a file with a different name without ever writing to a file called "scratch".

Comment: @jjaderberg That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can set the name of a buffer with `:file`:

```
:file foo
```

This doesn't affect the `modified` status of the buffer.  And you can set the `modified` status of a buffer by setting the `modified` option:

```
:setlocal modified
```

This doesn't affect the name of the buffer (or other attributes, for that matter).

Comment: Thank you. Digging into this further, it seems `:0file` will remove the name of the current buffer. And `:setlocal modified` will indeed restore its modified state. So I could achieve what I want with: `:w somename`, `:0f`, `:setlocal modified`

Answer (score 0):

1. Open file for edit and make edits

```
     vi testFile
```

2. Write to the new file (as you did)

```
     :w newFilename
```

3. Return to first buffer

```
    :buf testFile
```

4. continue editing testFile buffer from where you saved to newFilename buffer

Comment: Thank you, but I'm starting out with an unnamed buffer here – I can't open Vim with a filename. And since the buffer has a name after your step 1, I believe step 2 won't change the buffer name, so I don't think your step 3 will have any effect.

Comment: Can you instead open with a name?  I always do even if it's just "temp" 

Also, there are other buffer commands for listing and I believe cycling through the available buffers,

Comment: That's not unreasonable, but this is for a plugin where I want to be able to handle unnamed buffers gracefully. I did get a working solution from @buff's answer if you're curious :)